# UISearchController and UISearchBar are not animating properly and are changing the Status Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, search

I'm working in a fresh project with Xcode 7.2, built against iOS 9.2, and testing on an iPhone 6. This project is less than a week old with a minimal framework primarily defined in a storyboard.

The storyboard has a float of `UINavigationController` > `UITabBarController` > `UITableViewController`, which is the one with the search code, defined below.

In my Info.plist, I have `Status bar style` set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`, `Status bar is initially hidden` set to `YES`, and `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `No`.

In the storyboard, I do not have a `UISearchBar` or anything else on the `UITableViewController` other than the prototype `UITableViewCell`.

Nowhere in my simple app do I override `preferredStatusBarStyle` and on the storyboard I have made sure all the `Status Bar` values are set to `Light Content` for every controller, just to be safe.

The `UITableViewController` has the following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchResultsController = MovieSearchResultsController()
    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

}
```

When the `UISearchBar` is selected, the entire view shifts upwards, covering the `UINavigationBar`. This is great, except the status bar changes to black text and the `UISearchBar` disappears.

I'm pulling my hair out and have been pouring over this all day. I've read so many answers on Stack and nothing seems to work.

When I run [Apple's UISearchController demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html), it works exactly as intended. I've tried to replicate this exactly and I'm having no luck. I've also tried picking apart the demo and inserting my own code and it seems to work fine, short of completely redoing the project in this container, which seems highly unnecessary.

For the time being, I've just set `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `false` and removed `self.definesPresentationContext`.

**My Goal:**

- The status bar will remain with a white text color and the background color of my `UINavigationBar`.
- The `UINavigationBar` will hide as the `UISearchBar` animates, shifting the view up.
- The animation will flow smoothly, just like in the Apple demo. No jumpiness or strange delay.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve it?